# Kendo DataSource: How to set filters before fetch without sending two httprequests

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, odata

Environment:

- kendo version: 2013.1.319
- dataSource:

  ```
  productsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      type: "odata",
      transport: {
          read: "http://www.mydomain.com/odata.svc/products",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json"
      }
      schema: {
          type: "json",
          data: function(data){
              return data.value;
          },
          total: function(data){
              return data['odata.count'];
          },
          model: product
      },
      pageSize: 50,
      serverPaging: true,
      serverFiltering: true,
      serverSorting: true
  });
  ```
- Get data:

  productsDataSource.filter([{ field: "Id", operator: "eq", value: 5 }]); //this will send an httprequest

  productsDataSource.fetch(function (e) {
      tempDataStorage = e.items;
      //more logic to dealing with the data;
  });
- problems:

  1. need to use the fetch method of the dataSource for data processing(widgets initialization, data binding...etc);
  2. avoid sending two httprequests when setting filters before fetch;
  3. the filter condition need to be changed at runtime.

Comment: I think change the _filter is not recommended. The telerik´s team should provide a better way to manipulate the filters array before the bind operation. the filter method causes a second server operation, that´s not good at all. for now, changing the _filter seems to be the unique solution, but, pay attention, they can change the name of this variable in the future and you application can break then.

Answer (score 5):

```
productsDataSource._filter = { logic: 'and', filters: [
{ field: "Id", operator: "eq", value: 5 }]};
```

I've found this to work. Set the internal property to a full filter object. You can then call fetch afterwards. I've not yet found a way to change the page size without triggering a fetch however.

Answer (score 4):

You can user [`filter`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-filter.operator-String) in the `DataSource` configuration. This should issue only one request with the filtering conditions that you specify in the `DataSource` configuration.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I have to change filter conditions at runtime. configuration can only be set one time, am i right?

Comment: You set filter configuration using `datasource.read`` whenever you want and as soon as you set a new filter condition Kendo UI invokes `transport.read` with the new conditions.

Comment: The only method in dataSource that has a callback function is fetch, that's why I choose it. the dataSource.data() is still empty after dataSource.read() is called, this becomes a problem because i cannot initialize my widgets right after that. is there anyway that i can reset the filters before i call the fetch method and do not send a httprequest automatically(before fetch)? Thanks.

Comment: How / Where do you use the datasource? Widget as `Grid` have options (as `autoBind`) for not loading from the datasource when initialized

Comment: Widgets like DropDownList and "source binding + kendo-template". Widgets is OK because there no need to change filter conditions; for "**source** binding + kendo-template", I have to update the **source** property(in a viewModel) in the fetch callback.

Comment: Sorry! still not getting what you are trying to do. If you need to do some processing to received data just implement the logic in `schema.parse` or `schema.data`. If you need to change what this function does... just do it: implement some sort of logic that changes what it does... Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/VJhEd/1/) example where I change parse processing and then apply a filter condition.

Answer (score 3):

Set the _filter field in the dataSource using `productsDataSource._filter = [{ field: "Id", operator: "eq", value: 5 }];` and then manually initiate the request for remote data when you are ready using `productsDataSource.read();`

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is an old question, it comes in google results. So even though I don't know if it is valid for kendo version: 2013.1.319, but there is currently a method

```
dataSource.query({
  sort: { field: "ProductName", dir: "desc" },
  page: 3,
  pageSize: 20
});
```

This can set multiple options like sort, filter paging etc in a single call and returns a promise.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-query

Answer (score 0):

Bind event listener to datasource which initializes widget and then use filter method.

```
datasource.one('requestEnd', function(){
   // initialize or/and bind widget
});
datasource.filter({ /*your filter*/ })
```