# explictly setting filter for datasource KendoUI

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-listview

I wanted to explictly set a filter for populating KendoUI list view , 
As per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635245/kendo-datasource-how-to-set-filters-before-fetch-without-sending-two-httpreques/24839852#24839852) I did this,

```
        $(function () {
        var model = {
            items:ko.observableArray([])
        }
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            serverFiltering: true,
            pageSize: 20, serverPaging: true,
            schema: { data: function (data) { return data.Items; }, total: function (data) { return data.Count; } },
            type: 'odata',
            change: function () {
                var items = this.data();
                console.log(items);
                model.items.removeAll();
                for (var x=0;x<items.length;x++) {
                    model.items.push(items[x]);
                }
            },
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/my/thumbnail/",
                    dataType: "json",
                }
            },
        });


        dataSource._filter = [{ field: "Id", operator: "eq", value: 149 }];
        ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("thumbnailListView"));
        dataSource.read();

    });
</script>
```

this is what I get in dataSource,

```
   ct.extend.init {options: Object, _map: Object, _prefetch: Object, _data: ct.extend.init[0], _pristineData: Array[0]…}
_aggregate: undefined
_changeHandler: function () {
_data: ct.extend.init[0]
_destroyed: Array[0]
_events: Object
_filter: Array[1]
0: Object
field: "Id"
operator: "eq"
value: 149
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
_group: Array[0]
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
_map: Object
_page: 1
_pageSize: 20
_prefetch: Object
_pristineData: Array[0]
_pristineTotal: 0
_ranges: Array[0]
_sort: undefined
_total: undefined
_view: Array[0]
data: function (e){var n=this;return e===t?n._data:(n._data=this._observe(e),n._pristineData=e.slice(0),n._ranges=[],n._addRange(n._data),n._total=n._data.length,n._pristineTotal=n._total,n._process(n._data),t)}
options: Object
reader: dt.extend.init
table: null
transport: dt.extend.init
__proto__: n.extend.r
```

But on dataSource.read() , I get this error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'.

Comment: Did you try using `dataSource.filter(...)` for setting the filter programmatically? See documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-filter)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure is this helps but you can try this approach-

1. get an array to iterate over [all data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-data): `dataSource.data()`
2. access a [specific item](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-at): `dataSource.at(1)`
3. get [filtered data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-view): `datasource.view()`
4. get a [pure JS array](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/observablearray#methods-toJSON) back: `dataSource.data().toJSON()`